# Wagtail "Template-loader postmortem" the source exists though

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, wagtail

ok, my problem is that template-loader doesn't find a file that DOES exist !!
First of all, this happened when I tried to change the hierarchy of my site :

I tried to put a new kind of page (MainPage) as the first child of the Root, and set all other pages (Home and Events) below it. So HomePage that used to be at the root level is now set to be a child of MainPage and Events are childs of HomePage.

I made all of this through the wagtail's admin interface.
Next I created a main_page.html template which loads base.html and the used tags.

But now it's going tricky :

As everything was working very well, after the hierarchy changes, the template loader doesn't find anymore a file used for the navigation bar :
top_menu_children.html. Here is my hierarchy :

```
- my-site/
     |  - my-app/
             |  - templatetags/
                       |  - my-app_tags.py
             |  - templates/
                       |  - my-app/
                              |  - main_page.html
                              |  - events_page.html
                              |  - home_page.html
                              |  - tags/
                                     |  - top_menu.html
                                     |  - top_menu_children.html
     |  - my-site/
             |  - templates/
                       |  - base.html
```

Now here is the content of my-app_tags.py :

```
...
@register.inclusion_tag('my-app/tags/top_menu_chidren.html'
                        ,takes_context=True)
    def top_menu_children(context, parent):
        menuitems_children = parent.get_children()
        menuitems_children = menuitems_children.live().in_menu()
        return {
           'parent': parent,
            'menuitems_children': menuitems_children,
            'request': context['request'],
        }
```

and finally this is an extract of the error I get :

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: ../my-site/my-site/templates/my-app/tags/top_menu_chidren.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: .../my-site/my-app/templates/my-app/tags/top_menu_chidren.html (Source does not exist)
```

The second one SHOULD match !!!!

I'm sorry if it seems a bit messy but i tried to describe the context :
the template loader is searching at the right place a file that does exists but now says that it doesn't.

Please help because I really don't know what is the problem, i just need a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the name of your template in your template tag registration:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('my-app/tags/top_menu_chidren.html'
                    ,takes_context=True)
```

it reads `top_menu_chidren.html` and it should be `top_menu_children.html` as this is the name of your template.

**EDIT**

Your template loader search for a template named `top_menu_chidren.html` or in your **templates/my-app/tags** folder you have a template named `top_menu_children.html`.

Comment: my god even when you answered me I couldn't see the missing "l" ... Thank you very much, sometimes we need another look